# How do I align strings in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Suppose I'm working with a poem and I want to show it on my flutter app. However, I have two issues:

1. I am using Firestore database and strings are stored like paragraphs
2. I don’t know how to display something in Flutter with alignment.

A possible solution I have is to store strings with comma (,) notation and use a loop on the string to create new lines when there is a comma, but still I'm not sure.

Comment: What is it exacty that you are trying to achieve? There are lot of ways to align text in Flutter. You can use an `Alignment` widget, `textAlign` property of `Text` widget and more...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the RichText widget. You can create a lot of TextSpan on the children property, one for each row of the poem